# How to run a useffect when something happens in another component in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

EssayManager.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import CollegeEssays from "./CollegeEssays";
import { getDocs, collection } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../Firebase";
import TextEditor from "./TextEditor";

function EssayManager() {
  const [college, setCollege] = useState();
  const [collegeList, setColleges] = useState([]);
  const [essayList, setEssays] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("user") == null) {
      sessionStorage.setItem(
        "previousPage",
        "http://localhost:3000/essaymanager"
      );
      window.location = "http://localhost:3000/signIn";
    }
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadUser() {
      const colleges = await getDocs(
        collection(db, JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("user")).email)
      );
      colleges.forEach((doc) => {
        if (doc.id != "user") {
          setColleges((current) => [
            ...current,
            <div
              className="collegedivclass"
              id={doc.id}
              key={doc.id}
              onClick={() => changeCollege(doc.id)}
            >
              <CollegeEssays name={doc.id} />
            </div>,
          ]);
        }
      });
    }
    loadUser();
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {

  }, [])
  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadEssays() {
      setEssays([]);
      const essays = await getDocs(
        collection(
          db,
          JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("user")).email,
          `${college}`,
          "essays"
        )
      );
      essays.forEach((doc) => {
        if (doc.id != "exists") {
          setEssays((current) => [
            ...current,
            <li key={doc.id}>
              <TextEditor
                prompt={doc.id}
                text={doc.data().text}
                count={doc.data().count}
                countType={doc.data().countType}
                college={college}
              />
            </li>,
          ]);
        }
      });
    }
    if (college != undefined) {
      loadEssays();
    }
  }, [college]);
  async function changeCollege(id) {
    setCollege(id);
  }
  return (
    <>
      {collegeList.length > 0 ? (
        <div id="page">
          <ul id="listul">{collegeList}</ul>
          <h6>*New essays will only show up when the college is clicked again</h6>
          <h1 id="collegename">{college}</h1>
          <ul>{essayList}</ul>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <h1>No Colleges in List</h1>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
export default EssayManager;
```

CollegeEssays.js

```
import React from "react";
import AddEssay from "./AddEssay";
import "../UsersEssays.css";

function CollegeEssays(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="useressay">
        <h5 id={props.name}>{props.name}</h5>
        <AddEssay id="addessaybutton" college={props.name} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default CollegeEssays;
```

AddEssay.js

```
import React from "react";
import Popup from "reactjs-popup";
import { useState } from "react";
import { db } from "../Firebase";
import { setDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import "../UsersEssays.css";

function AddEssay(props) {
  const [prompt, setPrompt] = useState("");
  const [countType, setCountType] = useState();
  const [count, setCount] = useState("");
  const college = props.college;

  function handlePrompt(e) {
    setPrompt(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleCountType(e) {
    if (
      document.getElementById("wordCount").checked ||
      document.getElementById("charCount").checked
    ) {
      document.getElementById("countLabel").hidden = false;
      document.getElementById("count").hidden = false;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("countLabel").hidden = true;
      document.getElementById("count").hidden = true;
    }
    setCountType(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleCount(e) {
    setCount(e.target.value);
  }

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await setDoc(
        doc(
          db,
          JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("user")).email,
          college,
          "essays",
          prompt
        ),
        {
          text: "",
          countType: countType,
          count: count,
        }
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
    }
  }

  return (
    <Popup id="popup" trigger={<button>Add</button>} modal>
      {(close) => (
        <div id="form">
          <form>
            <h3>Add an essay for {college}</h3>
            <label>Prompt:</label>
            <input type="text" value={prompt} onChange={handlePrompt} />
            <br />
            <fieldset onChange={handleCountType}>
              <legend>Count Type</legend>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="countType"
                id="wordCount"
                value="Word Count"
              />
              <label>Word Count</label>
              <br />
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="countType"
                id="charCount"
                value="Character Count"
              />
              <label>Character Count</label>
              <br />
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="countType"
                id="noCount"
                value="No Count"
              />
              <label>No Count</label>
              <br />
            </fieldset>
            <label id="countLabel" hidden>
              Count:
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={count}
              id="count"
              onChange={handleCount}
              hidden
            />
            <br />
            <input
              type="submit"
              value="Add"
              onClick={(event) => {
                handleSubmit(event);
                close();
              }}
            />
          </form>
        </div>
      )}
    </Popup>
  );
}

export default AddEssay;
```

I'm using firestore through the google cloud to save the essay information. The essays are pulled from the database and rendered only when the user selects a new college, changing the college variable and triggereing the useeffect. This means that if a user adds a new essay through the essay form, that new essay won't show up until the user selects the college again.

I'm hoping to find a way to cause the useeffect or at least the function in EssayManager.js to trigger when the user submits the form in AddEssay.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your EssayComponent with a useContext provider. In this provider, you create the essay state. In this way, any component within this context can access the essay state.

https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useContext